How do I find the CMOS Battery Health in a PC
This is exhausting, and I'm wondering if there is any solution.
Trying to find info specifically on my CMOS battery on my computer.  It is a PC, not a laptop.
The PC is working fine, but CoPilot only shows info relating to "powercfg /batteryreport" and "powercfg /energy"
Other commands I've tried are "WMIC PATH Win32_Battery Get EstimatedChargeRemaining", "Get-WmiObject Win32_Battery | Select-Object Status" and "Get-WmiObject Win32_Battery | Select-Object -Property *", all to no avail.
I have run Microsoft's Speccy, and it only shows Brand, Version and Date.
But I am not looking for a tool, but a powershell/ vb script/ batch script to find the info.
Help?

I do not think you can check programmably the status of this battery. Shutdown your computer and use multimeter to check the voltage.

Sometimes this voltage is visible on hardware monitoring tools. Either way, keep in mind that voltage does not easily translate to state of charge.

The problem with trying to measure that battery voltage is that you can only really do it when the computer is off as it is almost entirely a backup battery for the CMOS and not the general working voltage source for the electronics. It requires more effort to set up the electronics to measure the voltage for something that should only really need replacing after 4-5 years.

Might be easier to pull the battery, slap it in a volt meter and then replace it anyway.  Its  generally a cheap CR2032 good for at least 5 years,

@Criggie Voltmeters in isolation are no good for batteries like this. You need some kind of load to test it properly, since the open-circuit voltage can be quite high even when the battery is drained.

@Bob one of my multimeters has battery test modes with a load. it draws more current on the "1.5V" battery check position than the "9V" one. The latter, designed for PP3s, is still a bit much for CR2032s, but a good test

@FormalMoss: Why do you believe the CMOS battery is unhealthy?

The CMOS battery is not monitored by the computer's hardware.  Therefore, the battery status is not able to be seen by the operating system.
I can only assume that since CMOS batteries often last for many years, even a decade or more in some cases, there was never really a need to monitor them.  Also, as most are CR2032 batteries (in desktops), they are incredibly easy and cheap to replace.

The CMOS battery is usually not monitored.  My home fileserver shows a "VBAT: 3.23 V", but that's presumably because I built it from secondhand server parts.

@Mark Thats new to me.  I have never seen a PC/laptop monitor a CMOS battery before.  Nor have a seen a server do it either...  But maybe that has changed in recent times?

@Keltari actually it is quite old feature, for example supermicro from around 2012-14 or recent consumer motherboard

When I use desktops, I usually put two standard alkaline AA cells wrapped in insulation tape somewhere in the case (also 3 Volts like the CR2032), and wire them to where the CR2032 was. Duracell AAs usually last at least 10 years, and they have a much higher capacity than the CR2032 so you can use the "shelf life" estimate on the box (as if they're sitting in the cupboard instead of in the PC).

@ReversedEngineer If you're doing that, you're probably better off using a 3V CR123(A) primary cell (make sure it's non-rechargeable; the rechargeable Li-ion ones are 3.7V). They're the same Lithium primary chemistry as a CR2032, just much larger. They'll have a much closer discharge voltage curve and won't leak like Alkaline cells are prone to doing, especially since PCs are quite warm environments often well above room temperature.

Good idea, @Bob, I'll try that next time. Never had them more that several years, and they never leaked, at least not through the insulation tape they were wrapped in before soldering (I'm not intending to open another debate about that ). The Duracells I have in front of me now say "Good until 03/2032". The idea is that the "discharge voltage curve" is irrelevant, since the discharge current is negligible when using AAs instead of a CR2032. But you're right about PCs being much warmer inside than room temperature, which will increase the self-discharge rate.
